# How to serialize custom classes as structs using pyarrow in dask dataframes?

Tags: python, parquet, dask, pyarrow

I have dask dataframe that has a column of type List[MyClass]. I want to save this dataframe to parquet files. Dask is using pyarrow as the backend, but it supports only primitive types.

```py
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd


class MyClass:

    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a


def transform(v):
    return [MyClass(v)]


a = [[1], [2], [3]]
pdf = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(a)
ddf = dd.from_pandas(pdf, npartitions=1)
result = ddf.assign(mycol=ddf[0].apply(transform))
result.to_parquet('my_parquet.parquet')
```

So when i try to save it i get this error:

`ArrowInvalid: Error inferring Arrow data type for collection of Python objects. Got Python object of type MyClass but can only handle these types: bool, float, integer, date, datetime, bytes, unicode, decimal`.

Obviously i have to convert `MyClass` to pyarrow compatible struct type, but i can't find a way how to do this. Pyarrow & dask have some serialization features (like this https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/ipc.html#serializing-custom-data-types), but seems like that's not quite the thing i need.

Comment: Are you prepared to handle the serialisation (class<->bytes) yourself, and store the bytes only?

Comment: no, i wanted to serialize with dask / pandas and deserialize with spark. Since complex schemas are not supported yet in pyarrow, i decided to use json as the intermediate format for this case.

Comment: Does spark handle JSON now? I previously didn't. In any case, glad if that solves things (feel free to post an answer), but I am surprised, as I thought you wanted to store python classes.

Answer (score 4):

a bit late, but maybe this [link](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/ipc.html#serializing-custom-data-types) can help others.

It basically comes down to defining custom hand-made serialization functions. For example here's your class:

```
class MyData:
    def __init__(self, name, data):
        self.name = name
        self.data = data
```

You write functions to convert to/from this class like:

```
def _serialize_MyData(val):
    return {'name': val.name, 'data': val.data}

def _deserialize_MyData(data):
    return MyData(data['name'], data['data']
```

Then initialize a context from these functions to later give to the Serialization/Deserialization methods:

```
context = pa.SerializationContext()
context.register_type(MyData, 'MyData',
                      custom_serializer=_serialize_MyData,
                      custom_deserializer=_deserialize_MyData)
```

Now you call the `serialize`/`deserialize` methods and pass them the context:

```
buf = pa.serialize(val, context=context).to_buffer()
restored_val = pa.deserialize(buf, context=context)
```

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to deserialize just part of the data? 
For example if data is huge, and I just want to extract the name, is there a way to extract just that from the serialized data?